# Cannot add shop to facebook page

Tags: facebook

When I am trying to create shop for my facebook page, it shows following error message. "Facebook Page shops are no longer available in your area"

In India, it has the facility of page shop as per the facebook documentation

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/549256849084694

Please advice how can I create a shop for my facebook page.
Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fak6H.png)

Comment: _"In India, it has the facility of page shop as per the facebook documentation"_ - I don't see "India" mentioned on that page. Are you referring to a specific region or something?

Comment: Are you sure that page shop is supported in india? because we are getting above error when try to create facebook  page shop.

Comment: Well I was asking _you_ whether you were sure, because the Help page you linked to, does _not_ mention India as a supported market ... So I am guessing, that it is _not_ supported currently.

Comment: Can you please try to load that Help page in incognito window and check if India exist. Because when I check here India is there.